# Can the test configuration file be parameterized?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-load-testing

Is it possible to pass parameters to [loadTestConfigFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-load-test-v1?view=azure-pipelines)?
I want to have parameters for TestId and DisplayName in the [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/reference-test-config-yaml#load-test-definition) file so that I can use it for different environments and stages. This way the testId won't change and all runs of one environment will be within one testId. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The TestId and DisplayName can be specified directly in Load Test config file(yaml).
[image]

If you still would like to have parameters for them, you can use task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) in DevOps pipeline before the loadtest task.

Sample to change `testId`:

step1： Change the testId value in config yaml.

[image]

2. Add variable `SampleTest` in pipeline:

[image]

3. Add replace token task before loadtest task:

```
    - task: replacetokens@5
      inputs:
        targetFiles: '**/SampleApp.yaml'
        encoding: 'auto'
        tokenPattern: 'default'
        writeBOM: true
        actionOnMissing: 'warn'
        keepToken: false
        actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
        enableTransforms: false
        enableRecursion: false
        useLegacyPattern: false
        enableTelemetry: true

    - task: AzureLoadTest@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
        loadTestConfigFile: 'SampleApp.yaml'
        resourceGroup: $(loadTestResourceGroup)
        loadTestResource: $(loadTestResource)
        env: |
          [
            {
            "name": "webapp",
            "value": "$(webAppName).azurewebsites.net"
            }
          ]
          
    - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/loadTest
      artifact: results
```

4. Check in Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: It is a workaround though. Seems strange the file is not parameterized.

Comment: As per the doc [Test configuration YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/reference-test-config-yaml), the testid and displayname are required to display on azure, i'd prefer to edit in in DevOps pipeline. :)

Comment: Hi @EnxhiLeba, if it works for you, would you please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that it could also help others who has same query? Thanks.